# How to change back button route in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

i am using react-navigation (stack-navigation). i want to change my header back button icon route.

1. Home
2. BookTicket
3. MyBookings

   these are the screens i have in my project.Now when i click header back button in  MyBookings screen it should route to Home Screen.

Comment: Have you tried using `navigation.navigate([path])`?

Comment: ya i tried but didn't work for my case.but thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be back button in default if your stackNavigator stack is properly configured.

But if you would like to replace the default button just add **headerLeft** and pass your custom component Screen Navigation Options in the page you want to change the back button handler

```
CreateAccountScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
  title: 'Create Account',
  headerTintColor: '#fefefe',
  headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
  headerLeft: {()=>(
          <Icon name="chevron-left"
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
                size={35} color="white"/>
       )}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

So, the default functionality of React Navigation is:-
If you press the Back Button on Mybookings screen, it will take you to previous screen i.e, BookTicket screen.
To override that you could do something like this on MyBookings screen:-

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation';
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return{
    headerLeft:(<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Home')}}/>)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don´t want to use custom back buttons (e. g. to avoid dealing with the different "native" button designs), there is also the possibility to [reset the navigation state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions.html#reset). In your case like this:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 2,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'BookTicket' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MyBookings' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

This way you just set a stack of navigations and let it [jump to the index position](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions.html#how-to-use-the-index-parameter).

*This setup must be done at the departing scene, so that in the next scene the back button works as expected.*

But I prefer this way anyway, because it allows to maintain the default look of the header and keeps the stack clean. If you use `navigation.navigate` instead of `navigation.back` the stack becomes totally wrong for the back button.