# How to customize back function react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'am still learning `React Native`. I've created simple app with `login and logout` flow.

I use `react-navigation` for routing my app and `async-storage` to save `user session`.

When I `login` the app successfuly navigate to `profile` screen.

Here's the problem when I click the `back` button I'm on the `login` screen again. What I want is the app navigate to the `home` screen.

How can I solve this ? Can I customize the `back` function like :

```
back(){
  if(login){
     this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can put a check on `ComponentDidMount` and check for if `user session` is active on `async-storage`. If yes, navigate to Home screen.

Comment: I will try it @gaback

Comment: @gaback It's not like what I want. the app `navigate` immediately to the `home` screen after `login`. I want the app navigate only if I `press` the `back` button

Comment: you keep `user session on async storage` even after user have logged out or close the app?

Comment: @gaback yes, it's saved

Comment: You customize the back button yourself or you are using default back button

Comment: for now I use the default

Comment: The best way I could think of now is have a `global variable`, something like `moveHome: False`. Whenever you navigate to `profile` screen, change it to `True`. So in `ComponentDidMount` at `login` screen, you  check if `moveHome is True` insteads of using `user session`

Comment: I hope you using react-navigation library to handle app navigation. My suggestion is to use Authentication flows of react-navigation. I have tried it. not happens this kind of issues. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: [I answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059824/9450776). Maybe this is what you are looking for? In short: you reset your [navigation state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions.html#reset) to change the back route to what you want.